# My macvim showed me an error message "E474: invalid argument"

Tags: vim

When I was opening the cpp file with my macvim, it showed me this error message. Actually, file seemed to open well. But I don't know why this message has appeared. My error message is as below.

```
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/defaults.vim[96]../Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/filetype.vim[2259]../Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/menu.vim[52]../Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/lang/menu_ko_kr.utf-8.vim[264]../Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/lang/macvim_menu/menu_ko_kr.utf-8.apple.vim 수행중 에러 발견:
  10 줄:
E474: 잘못된 인자
```

This was all. There was no comment like "listchar~~blahblah". Translate this to English, it is...

```
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/defaults.vim[96]../Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/filetype.vim[2259]../Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/menu.vim[52]../Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/lang/menu_ko_kr.utf-8.vim[264]../Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/lang/macvim_menu/menu_ko_kr.utf-8.apple.vim <- while progressing this, error has been found:
  10 line:
E474: Invalid Argument
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you always get that error when starting Vim, or is it only for that particular file, or is it for _any_ `.cpp` file?

Comment: Always when I try to use Vim. I tried this with other files like .cpp .C .h

Comment: There is something on line 10 in `menu_ko_kr.utf-8.apple.vim` vim doesn't like.

Comment: I found `menu_ko_kr.utf-8.apple.vim` which I've never seen before. And it warns me that  "This file was generated from Apple localization glossaries (language). Do not modify this file directly!". So I couldn't edit anything. The line 10 was `menutrans Save\ As…<Tab>:sav 별도\ 저장...` which seems to translate the language.
(Thanks to all of you for helping me solve this problem)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with the following method. Open the file and remove the "..." or other strange thing at the end of line 10.

> 1 " This file was generated from Apple localization glossaries
> (Korean).
> 2 " Do not modify this file directly!
> 3
> 4 menutrans New\ Window 새로운\ 윈도우
> 5 menutrans New\ Tab 새로운\ 탭
> 6 menutrans Open… 열기…
> 7 menutrans Open\ Recent 최근\ 사용\ 열기
> 8 menutrans Close\ Window:qa 윈도우\ 닫기
> 9 menutrans Close:q 닫기
> 10 **menutrans Save\ As…:sav 별도\ 저장 <-- removed the "..." at the
> end.**
> 11 menutrans Save\ All 모두\ 저장